# Symmetries of Dual Riemann tensor

Tags: general-relativity, symmetry, tensor-calculus, curvature

In four dimensions, the dual of the Riemann tensor  is defined as
\begin{align}
^*R^{\mu}{}_{\nu}{}^{\gamma\delta}=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}R^{\mu}{}_{\nu\alpha\beta}\,.
\end{align}
I have always heard that it has the same symmetries that the Riemann tensor, however, I am confused about that, since apparently,
\begin{align}
^*R_{\rho\sigma}{}^{\mu\nu}\neq \,^*R^{\mu\nu}{}_{\rho\sigma}\,,
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
^*R_{\rho\sigma}{}^{\mu\nu}&=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{\mu\nu}{}_{\alpha\beta}R_{\rho\sigma}^{\alpha\beta}\,,\\
^*R^{\mu\nu}{}_{\rho\sigma}&=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{\rho\sigma}{}^{\alpha\beta}R^{\mu\nu}_{\alpha\beta}\,,
\end{align}
not allowing us to define $^*R^{\mu\nu}_{\rho\sigma}$, unlike the Riemann tensor. Could you clarify me what are the symmetries of $^*R^{\mu}{}_{\nu}{}^{\rho\sigma}$?

Comment: Well, most of your index placements are wrong. For the last two expressions, the RHS is ill-defined.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but why?

Comment: Interchange of indices will satisfy $^*R_{abcd}={R^*}_{cdab}$. Even the cyclic identity $^*R_{[abc]d}=0$ is true only when ricci tensor vanishes. For details please see the discussion in section 4.6 of "Spinors and Space-Time, Volume-I"